# Deprecation warning for moment timezone

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

```
var viewValue = "GMT"; 

return moment(moment().tz(viewValue).format('LLL'));
```

Above `return` throw below error, can you please let me know how to fix below issue:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `moment().tz('GMT').format('LLL')` results in a string like this:

```
May 3, 2018 7:29 AM
```

The above string is not in a valid ISO format. That's why you receive this warning because if you pass this to the `moment` constructor, you're creating a MomentJS object again.

To mitigate, you need to specify the format of the string to parse it correctly:

```
moment(moment().tz('GMT').format('LLL'), 'MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm A');
```

Answer (score 0):

As warning clearly shows that returned value (Date format) from your code is not supported by `momentjs`. This format is deprecated and will be removed in future.

So solution for this is to choose any of the format from below link:

Check **Supported ISO 8601 strings** & **The RFC 2822 date time format** here http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/